# On the basis of record in a single column, update a new date column

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, csv

Input file looks like:

| policy | eff_date | cust_id |
| --- | --- | --- |
| abcd | 2/12/2020 | 9879 |
| bcdf | 2/10/2020 | 654654 |
| bcdf | 3/11/2020 | 9879 |
| abcd | 5/11/2020 | 64643 |

On the basis of duplicate policy number, i want to update minimum eff_date for the duplicate one in eff_Date column

Among 2 abcd record, lower eff_date is 2/12/2020, so 2/12/2020 should be updated for the duplicate abcd as well. DROP IS NOT REQUIRED.

My output should look like:

| policy | eff_date | cust_id |
| --- | --- | --- |
| abcd | 2/12/2020 | 9879 |
| bcdf | 2/10/2020 | 654654 |
| bcdf | 2/10/2020 | 9879 |
| abcd | 2/12/2020 | 64643 |

Below is the code i tried, but is completely wrong it seems logic wise:

```
import pandas as pd

import io

df = pd.read_csv(r'C:\Users\n891000\Desktop\inputfile.csv',index_col=False, sep=',')

df=df.sort_values(by=['eff_Date'],ascending=False)

boolean = df.duplicated(subset=['policy']).any()

print(boolean, end='\n\n') # True

if boolean==True:

  for i in range(0,3):

    if df['policy'][i]== df['policy'][i+1]:

      df['eff_Date'][i]=min(df['eff_Date'][i+1])

df.to_csv(r'C:\Users\n891000\Desktop\outputfile.csv',index=False)
```

Please let me know where i am going wrong and how to achieve the output as stated above.

Comment: assuming datetime type: `df['eff_date'] = df.groupby('policy')['eff_date'].transform('min')`

Comment: Thank You @mozway .. it was a single liner problem and I made it complex.